# How can I see all the images in Sliding Image Gallery plugin in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, sliding

I want to do the effect presented by Mead Miracle http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGallery.aspx . So I am using this plug-in in jQuery. What I want is to navigate through all the images and not only three. So I want to have all the images shown and do the same effect. Does anyone know if I should change a parameter or is something I should do by scratch?

Thanks

Comment: It seems it corrects itself after the given width for the element you put this in. Which means it will always show 3 images, you could read up on the documentation for the plugin if there is any. 

If there isn't any good documentation I guess you have to dive into the code and try to make it show more pictures by altering the width function that optimises is for only 3 pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the code and it is obligatory to use 3 images, you can see it uses three variables:

```
 $.galleryUtility.centerImage = {};
    $.galleryUtility.rightImage = {};
    $.galleryUtility.leftImage = {};
```

I suggests you use something more elaborated like jquery cycle plugin, I don't know if you can find sth that adapts to your needs. Pls look here there is some good stuff:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/more.html?v2.23

**Edited:**

Look at the following articles, there are many options, I am not sure there is sth similar anyway:

http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/

I think you can tune the following galleries to do sth similar:

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyGallery/

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_multiple.html

Using scriptacolous, you have:

http://www.puidokas.com/portfolio/frogjs/

Comment: These are not exactly what I am looking for. Does anyone know another sliding Gallery where I can have more images?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find the solution? Did I help you anyway?